# Problems with sockets in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, server, blocking

first of all, I want to let you know that what you're about to read may be a little bit difficult to understand due to my brief explanation of my problem. I hope you understand anyway.

I created a server and I created a class which allows me to create different clients for the server. I'm using sockets, btw.
Okay so when I run the server it goes right until I create another client. It runs the **[WinError 10061]** error. As you can see, it seems as if this server doesn't allow more than one user at the time.

Anybody knows how to solve it? This is the first part of my server function:

```
def server():
    HOST = ''
    PORT = 50000             
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    #s.setblocking(False)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(5)
    lAct = []
    try:
        conn,addr = s.accept()
        conn.setblocking(0)
        lAct.append(ClientServidor(conn,addr))
    except InterruptedError:
        pass
```

ClientServidor is an external class, don't worry about it.

As you can see, I have the setblocking(False) commented. That's because when I try to put it into my code, it throws me the same error: **[WinError 10061]**

Thank you for your help and sorry if it may seem a dumb question, I'm all new into this!

Comment: WinError 10061 means *Connection refused*. Somewhere in the code you did not show (i.e. inside `ClientServidor`) you are probably doing a `connect` to some system which fails. Since the relevant part of the code is not shown no help is possible. Note that this is not related to setting the `conn` socket to non-blocking.

Comment: I don't think ClientServidor is the error, because it's hardly used here. 
What I do is just create two instances of the same class. One works, and the other does not. I don't get why. The class object initializes a socket and connects to it as you can see:

    `HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 50000
    self.s =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.s.connect((HOST,PORT))`
But thanks man!

Comment: *"The class object initializes a socket and connects to it as ...."* - as I suspected it connects. And there it probably throws the error. Python usually shows a stacktrace on error but you did not include one in your question. If you would take a closer look at the stacktrace my guess is that it will probably point to this part of the (not shown) code of `ClientServidor`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what you mean with stacktrace.

Comment: If you get an error and don't handle it a specific way you get a multi-line output which shows exactly where the error was thrown (which line of code) and from where this line of code was called etc, i.e. the full call stack, also called a stacktrace.

Comment: You really _haven't_ provided enough code here for us to help, but based on what you _have_ shown, I get the impression that you're trying to call `server()` twice or more in your program.  You can't bind to a port more than once.